# Getting request.form to act like raw_input in a text adventure game (twilio)

Tags: python, sms, twilio

----------------------- EDIT -----------------------

I still am not sure how to get the request.form['Body'] working properly. I am likely not using this request properly, but I'm not sure how else to use it. One suggestion was make a listener, but am not sure where to start on that.

So I guess now its:

1) where am I totally buggering up?
2) Any suggestions on how to make a listener?

Here's a skeleton of my set up:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from sys import exit

twil_number = "XXXXXXXXX"
sid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
tos = "XXXXXXXXXX"

client = TwilioRestClient(sid,token)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

##### get the SMS ####

def smsGet():

    try:
        action = request.form['Body']
    except RuntimeError:
        action = raw_input("> ")

    return action.lower()


### Snd the SMS ####
def smsSend(bods):

    client.sms.messages.create(to=tos, from_=twil_number, body= bods)


class TestClass(object):

    def doStuff(self):

        smsSend("Intro Text")

        ## I don't know why this is buggering up. ###
        go = smsGet()

        if go == "yes":
            smsSend("yes")
            exit(1)

        else:
            pass
            exit(1)


a = TestClass()
a.doStuff()



#### running the app ###

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

----------------------- older -----------------------
I'm making a text adventure game in twilio/python. There's no database or anything, Its just a python based text adventure that I run locally out of a shell.

All the sending SMS things are fine, but how  do I get something like this:

```
request.form['Body'].lower()
```

to work like this:

```
raw_input("> ").lower()
```

So far most things I've tried just have Flask throwing this error:

RuntimeError('working outside of request context')

So for context. A lot of my scenes are set up like this:

```
class Hallway(Scene):
    def enter(self):

        hall = "You pause in the Hallway. You could: Go to the bedroom. Go to the kitchen to see if there's food. Check on your human in the office."
        send_sms(hall)

        #action = raw_input("> ").lower() 
        #would like this to work like raw _input()
        action = request.form['Body'].lower() 

        if action == "kitchen":
            return 'kitchen'
        elif action == "bedroom":
            return 'bedroom'
        elif action == "office":
            return 'office'
        else:
            nope = "But I don't want to hang in the hallway..."
            send_sms(nope)
            return 'hallway'
```

And send_sms() is just this:

```
def send_sms(bods):

    client.sms.messages.create(body=bods,to=tos,from_=froms)
```

Any suggestions on where I'm totally mucking up?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why are you using `request.form['Body'].lower()` instead of `raw_input(…).lower()`, if the latter is what you want? And if it's command-line only, how is Flask involved?

Comment: Because I want to use my phone to send an sms response rather than typing it in a terminal. So I want the program to look at the contents of the sms body, and send an sms back based on what's in it.

As for Flask. Twilio docs say to use that and ngrok (or something similar) to set things up locally: 

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/sending-via-rest
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. And does that mean that you're only getting this error when you're running from the command line?

Comment: Yes. So it will send out the first scene sms fine, but then when it hits the request I get the Flask error in the command line. i just can't figure out where to put that request to avoid that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you probably want something like this (note that I haven't run this, so it may have some small bugs, but the idea should be sound):

## listener.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import twilio.twiml

import game

account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
twilio_client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

app = Flask(__name__)

games = {}

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def accept_response():
    from_number = request.values.get('From')
    body = request.values.get('Body')

    try:
        games[from_number].queue.put(body)
    except KeyError:
        games[from_number] = game.Game(twilio_client, from_number, "your number goes here")
        games[from_number].start()

    return str(twilio.twiml.Response())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## game.py

```
import queue
from threading import Thread

class Game(Thread)

    def __init__(self, twilio, to_number, from_number):
        Thread.__init__(self, name=to_number)
        self.twilio = twilio
        self.from_number = from_number
        self.to_number = to_number
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        # Game logic goes here, e.g.:
        action = self.send_sms("You're being chased by a thing!", wait_for_response=True)        
        if action == "stop":
            self.send_sms("That was silly. The thing eats you, you die.")
        elif action == "run":
            self.send_sms("You're too slow! The thing eats you, you die.")
        else:
            self.send_sms("I don't know what you're trying to do, but the thing eats you, you die.")

    def send_sms(self, body, wait_for_response=False):
        self.twilio.messages.create(body=body, to=self.to_number, from_=self.from_number)
        if wait_for_response:
            response = self.queue.get()
            return response
```

So, you run the listener, and with the correct configuration on the Twilio side it just sits there and listens for SMSs. When it receives one it checks to see if a game is already running for the user. If so, it sends the body of the SMS to the game, to be used as input. Otherwise, it kicks off a new game for that user.

Each Game instance is running in it's own thread, and you can use the send_sms method of a Game instance just like `raw_input`, that is, the user for that game will receive the string argument as an SMS, and their reply will be the return value.

<del>I don't know what the rest of your game logic looks like, but to integrate this with something like the Scene class in your question, you would probably want to have Scene's consructor take a Game as an argument and assign it to an attribute. So, then, in `enter()` you could write something like `action = this.game.send_sms('foo')`.</del>

It appears you can get the current thread object using `threading.current_thread()` (which in this case is the Game instance), so there's no need to pass it around. You can either call `threading.current_thread().send_sms` from anywhere, or wire it up in the constructor of your scenes.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using 2.7.5 and its telling me there's no module named 'queue'. 

Also game logic context, because I'm a n00b, I'm following this: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

So same deal on setup: Each scene is a class, with an enter function etc.

Comment: Against all reason (and the documentation), the module appears to be named "Queue", not "queue".

Comment: learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html seems reasonable enough. As long as you call `Engine.play` from the `Game.run` method (or possibly just merge the Engine class in the exercise with the Game class from this answer) and use `threading.current_thread().send_sms` instead of `raw_input` (and a modified version of `send_sms` that doesn't wait for a response instead of `print`) it should probably just work...

Comment: Yeah I'm going to give meshing them together a shot, for some reason I'm getting an AttributeError: 'TwilioRestClient' object has no attribute 'twiml'

Odd. Seeing as there's nothing out of the ordinary with return str(twilio.twiml.Response())

Comment: Ugh, yeah, that's what I get for not running the code. The variable "twilio" that I assigned the TwilioRestClient to was shadowing the module "twilio" that is the parent of the "twiml" module. I've fixed the example code.

Comment: Fact: I totally owe you some pie for helping.

Comment: Also I'm really sorry to ask, but I'm still a bit lost. Can you toss just a really basic if/else statement in the run function just so I can see if I'm doing this right? - Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I've added a simple example.

Comment: Hey. One last question. Do you know why, I get an AttributeError: 'Hallway' object has no attribute 'send_sms'? I am assuming it is because send_sms is self.send_sms Its in the hallway class, in a function called enter.

Frankly this setup is messy and I should re-do it all to something more straightforward. And by thing, I mean the setup I wrote, not your solutions, which make sense.

Comment: Belay that. Switched everything to functions. Works awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run that code from either inside Flask *or* from the command line, you'll need to write a function which will get the action, either from the `request` or using `raw_input`. It could look something like this:

```
from flask import request

def get_action():
    try:
        action = request.form['Body']
    except RuntimeError:
        action = raw_input("> ")
    return action.lower()
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. I no longer get Flask throwing an error. Now i just need to figure out how to request that body properly. I'll go do some research on that.